# How do I alter this unity 2d patrolling script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2d unity game and I had a script that patrols a platformer however now I need it to patrol between two walls, here's the code:

```
public float speed = 2f;

public Rigidbody2D rb;

public LayerMask groundLayers;

public TextMeshProUGUI m_Object;
public SpriteRenderer sp;
public Transform groundCheck;

bool isFacingRight = true;

RaycastHit2D hit;

private void Update()
{
    hit = Physics2D.Raycast(groundCheck.position, -transform.up, 1f, groundLayers);

    
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(hit.collider != false)
    {
        if (isFacingRight)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
            
        }
        else
        {

           
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        sp.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-transform.localScale.x, 1f, 1f);
        
    }
}
```

It uses tile maps and I have got a different set of tile map called enemy check and that is placed as the layer mask it also uses raycasts.

Answer (score 0):

you could possibly use an "obstacleLayer" instead of the ground layer to check for all layer masks you consider as obstacles, like walls, cubes, etc. You, of course, would need to change the logic in the fixed update, and flip the character where it actually has hit an obstacle. You can keep your gourndcheck to see if the character is able to move or not (avoiding holes in the map, hypothetically). You may also have to think about your movement logic as, currently, the character only moves horizontally.